# Can I pass a structure into a function that takes void*?

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, void-pointers

Since this is a void* I should be able to pass a pointer of anytype right? Why is the compiler giving me errors?

```
int cmp_func(void *, void *));

typedef struct word_{
  char key[WORD_SIZE];
  int *frequency;
} word;

Phash_table new_hash(int size, int (*hash_func)(char *), int (*cmp_func)(void *\
, void *));

int comp_function(struct word_ *word1,struct word_ *word2){
  if( word1->frequency < word2->frequency){
    return -1;
  }
  if(word1->frequency <  word2->frequency){
      return 1;
  }
  if(word1->frequency == word2->frequency){
    return 0;
  }
}
```

```
project4_functions.c:47:3: warning: passing argument 3 of 'new_hash' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
hash.h:38:13: note: expected 'int (*)(void *, void *)' but argument is of type 'int (*)(struct word_ *, struct word_ *)'
```

Comment: Why is `cmp_func` closed with two parentheses and where is the definition of `new_hash` or its usage?!

Comment: Seems an error unrelated to this function. Check new_hash function.

Comment: Also, any pointer can be sent to `void *`, but you are sending a pointer to `int (*)(void *, void *)` not a `void *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to make your compare function take void pointers as well:

```
int comp_function(void *a, void *b){
  struct word *word1 = a;
  struct word *word2 = b;
  // Use word1 and word2 as before.
}
```

---

Addendum, concerning *why* the compiler is giving you warnings:

To quote the c99 standard which I found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
>   type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
>   and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

This means that you can have code like the following, and the compiler won't issue the warning you're seeing:

```
void *a = NULL;
int (*f)(int a, char *b) = NULL;
a = f;
f = a;
```

It's tempting to extrapolate that this means the following will also work (after all, we're just substituting "void*" with "struct foo*", right?)

```
int (*f1)(void*, void*);
int (*f2)(struct foo*, struct foo*);
f1 = f2;
```

However, this generates your warning since it is **not** trying to assign a pointer type to a pointer to void (or vice-versa) as is allowed by the standard.  Instead it is trying to assign a value of type `int (*)(struct foo*, struct foo*)` to a variable of type `int (*)(void*, void*)`.

Of course, you *could* try to make the compiler happy with an explicit cast, which convinces the compiler that you must know what you're doing.  But in doing so you lose the privilege and safety of getting these warnings even when invoking "iffy" behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not match your code. Your code does not pass a structure pointer as a void pointer. It is passing one function pointer as another. The function pointers are not compatible, hence the error.

It is legal to pass a structure pointer where a void pointer is expected because a structure pointer can be implicitly *converted* to a void pointer. It is not required to be representationally identical to a void pointer. (There are some machines where structure pointers are not the same size as a void pointer, for example.)

By analogy consider the case of passing an int when a long is expected. This is legal because there is an implicit conversion, but that doesn't meant that a function accepting int is interchangeable with function accepting long.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the function pointer since your function prototype does not match the one the function expects:

```
typedef int (cmp_f)(void *, void *));
new_hash(..., ..., (cmp_f*)cmp_func_p);
```

Of course that typedef is not necessary, but it makes your code much more readable than without (you usually only do it without that typedef in exams where you are not allowed to use typedef for this purpose ;))

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Calling a function through a pointer to the wrong function type invokes undefined behavior. "A pointer is a pointer" is NOT true in C.

Comment: @R..: Do you have any reliable source for this? I think it's pretty common to cast function pointers if the original function has a `void*` argument while you want to save yourself from casting the argument inside the function body. gcc with `-Wall` also doesn't complain about it...

Comment: "If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined." (6.5.2.2) This is not just theoretical UB; it's actually going to break if the implementation uses different argument passing convention for different types of pointers. A practical reason to do this might be if the cpu has only a few registers that admit small-constant offsets in the opcodes that dereference them (most useful for structures), or if void pointers are larger than struct pointers.

Comment: By the way, the reason `gcc -Wall` cannot diagnose this is that calling the function as the wrong type takes place at a different location than passing the argument (e.g. one inside `qsort` and the other in your program). There's nothing wrong with casting function pointer types *as long as* they're cast back to the actual type before calling them.